# How do I fetch only the first element from the array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How do I fetch only the first element from the "topicsName" array?

Data I have input:

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("606b7046a0ccf72222c00c2f"),
        "groupId" : ObjectId("5f06cca74e51ba15f5167b86"),
        "insertedAt" : "2021-04-05T20:17:10.144521Z",
        "isActive" : true,
        "staffId" : [
            "606b6c34a0ccf72222c5a4df",
            "606b6c48a0ccf722228aa035"
        ],
        "subjectName" : "Maths",
        "teamId" : ObjectId("6069a6a9a0ccf704e7f4b537"),
        "updatedAt" : "2022-04-29T07:57:31.072067Z",
        "syllabus" : [
            {
                "chapterId" : "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3ee",
                "chapterName" : "chap1",
                "topicsName" : [
                    {
                        "topicId" : "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3ef",
                        "topicName" : "1.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "topicId" : "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3f0",
                        "topicName" : "1.2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "chapterId" : "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3f1",
                "chapterName" : "chap2",
                "topicsName" : [
                    {
                        "topicId" : "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3f2",
                        "topicName" : "2.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "topicId" : "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3f3",
                        "topicName" : "2.2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

---

The Query I used to try to fetch the element:- "topicId" : "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3ef" from the
"topicsName" array.

```js
db.subject_staff_database
  .find(
    { _id: ObjectId("606b7046a0ccf72222c00c2f") },
    {
      syllabus: {
        $elemMatch: {
          chapterId: "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3f1",
          topicsName: { $elemMatch: { topicId: "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3f2" } },
        },
      },
    }
  )
  .pretty();
```

---

I was trying to fetch only the first element from the "topicsName" array, but it fetched both the elements in that array.

Comment: *the first element* means the element with topicId 626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3f2 or the element of index 0 in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Ganesh Sowdepalli,
You are not only asking to "fetch only the first element from the array", but to fetch only the matching element of a nested array property of an object item in array.

Edit: (according to @ray's comment)
One way to do it is using an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.subject_staff_database.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {"_id": ObjectId("606b7046a0ccf72222c00c2f")}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      syllabus: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$syllabus",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item.chapterId", "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3f1"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$syllabus"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "syllabus.topicsName": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$syllabus.topicsName",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item.topicId", "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3f2"]}
        }
      },
      "syllabus.chapterId": 1,
      "syllabus.chapterName": 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KvEbbUulTra).

If you want the **actual first element**, not by _id, look [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/clxGTbqyZg6) on my first understanding to your question.

The aggregation pipeline allows us to do several operation on the results.
Since `syllabus` is an array that may contain more than one matching `chapterId`, we need to `$filter` it for the items we want.

Comment: Canonically thinking, OP should be looking for targeting element with given id. Your solution works for his given example since the targeted element is at index 0. If the element appears in index 1, your solution may not be what OP is looking for. However, this all depends on clarification from OP, which has been requested in the question comment.

Comment: I agree with you ray, my solution represents the way that I understand the question...

Comment: question is unclear, doesnt have expected output, both answers are fine i think, i would bet on serok, i thought the same.

Comment: I just changed it according to ray's interpretation, after looking closely at the OP attempted query :)

Comment: Agree with both of you. I actually appreciate nimrod's answer's tidiness and the detailed explanation. I simply want to bring out another approach to the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline.

1. `$match` with your given id locate documents
2. `$reduce` to flatten the `syllabus` and `topicsName` arrays
3. `$filter` to get the expected element

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "syllabus.topicsName.topicId": "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3ef"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      result: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$syllabus.topicsName",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      result: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$result",
          "as": "r",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$r.topicId",
              "626b9b94ae6cd2092024f3ef"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0kXRUpwsRLg) for your reference.